# ShinyR: run code only once after button clicked

Tags: r, shiny

I run fairly time consuming calculations in a Shiny app once users have selected input parameters. To make sure the calculations don't run unnecessary times I made the following action button:

```
 actionButton('seeData','see Data' )
```

I then tried to only have this time consuming calculation run once per button click (and never when there is no button click) with the following code:

```
 observeEvent( input$seeData, {

   ...long, includes several function calls...  

})
```

Within `observeEvent` I do reference other input parameters.

What I am finding is that the calculation does not run the first time until I press the button, no matter how many times I adjust input parameters. **However, once I press the button once, the calculation runs whenever any input parameter is changed.** Why is the code running a second, third, fourth time (etc) when I have only pressed the button once?

My goal would seem to be just the [typical use case](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/action-buttons.html), but I suppose there is something tricky with an `observe` or `isolate` aspect of `observeEvent` that I am not understanding. What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve one click-one calculation functionality?

Comment: `observeEvent` only triggers on the one event, not on other possibly-reactive variables contained within. If you need that, try `observe` instead. Second, you'll need to store a variable *somewhere* that defaults (say) to `FALSE`, and the first line of this `observe*` block is `if (! alreadyDone) { alreadyDone <- TRUE; ... }`.

Comment: @r2evans but my point is that it's not triggering only on button click. There is no other function in the app. It's triggering when parameters are adjuted regardless of button click.

Comment: Oh, huh ... I've tried and never was never able to get an `observeEvent` to trigger on anything other than the primary parameter. Though I don't think I can offer much more, when I'm confronted with confounded reactivity, I pepper other blocks with `message` calls to see the chain of events. Reactivity can be challenging to control well/efficiently. Sorry, I think I'm out.

Comment: Have you tried encapsulating your long functions in isolate({})? I was able to achieve this by running something like this:

`output$myOutput <- myFunction({
     input$actionButton
     isolate({ long running function })
})`

Comment: Don't use `observer()` or `reactive()` before `observeEvent()`

Answer (score 1):

use enable() and disable() on the action button.

so when the button is clicked (and before the long calculation) disable the button untill the calculation is done....

then at the end re-enable the button again...

Comment: clean solution! Requires library(shinyjs) and a useShinyjs() call in the ui.R

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/observeEvent.html) we can see a description of the uses of `observeEvent` and `eventReactive`. The interesting thing is in the example, where you can see how the reactiveness of the function is performed only in the moment when the button is clicked.

The approach is to define an `EventReactive` variable which contains the data to be displayed. This will make the function to retain its value even if the input changes. It will only change if the button is pressed.